# Jquery Show more div and show less div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I need help for *show more* and *show less* for sum div.

I have created this **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/jEWbWL)**  from *codepen.io*

In this **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/jEWbWL)** you can see 8 `div` red frame. I want to show if total `div` is greater than 4 then show more link will come and when i click show more link than i can see all `div` in the same page. Anyone can help me on this topic ?

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="post_wrap">
    <div class="pst">
      Post 1
    </div>
     <div class="pst">
      Post 2
    </div>
     <div class="pst">
      Post 3
    </div>
     <div class="pst">
      Post 4
    </div>
     <div class="pst">
      Post 5
    </div>
     <div class="pst">
      Post 6
    </div>
     <div class="pst">
      Post 7
    </div>
     <div class="pst">
      Post 8
    </div>
    <div class="test"><a href="">Show More</a></div> 
  </div>
  <div class="post_wrap">
    <div class="pst">
      Post 1
    </div>
     <div class="pst">
      Post 2
    </div>
     <div class="pst">
      Post 3
    </div>
     <div class="pst">
      Post 4
    </div>
     <div class="pst">
      Post 5
    </div>
     <div class="pst">
      Post 6
    </div>
     <div class="pst">
      Post 7
    </div>
     <div class="pst">
      Post 8
    </div>
    <div class="test"><a href="">Show More</a></div> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Check your CodePen in my edited answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS

```
div.test { display:none }
```

jQuery

1) First, you select every element with class '.post_wrap'

```
$('.post_wrap')
```

2) Then, with [each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) function jquery iterates over every .post_wrap element found in DOM and counts the child divs with class of .pst

```
$(this).find('div.pst').length;
```

**in more detail**

The $(this) refers to the element that each() function was applied to, in this case, $('post_wrap')
The find() function searches into the applied element and finds what it was told to find, in this case, finds every div.pst element
And, length counts the found elements

and stores the result in a variable named 'divNum'

Now, id divNum is greater than 4

```
if (divNum > 4)
```

show the div.test element

```
$('div.test').show()

$('.post_wrap').each(function() {
    var divNum = $(this).find('div.pst').length;
    if (divNum > 4) {
        $('div.test').show();
    }
})
```

Then if dv.test is visible:

```
$('div.test').click(function() {
    // show more divs
})
```

**EDIT -> your code pen**

Check the [CodePen](http://codepen.io/giannisKapa/pen/myVeBP)

jQuery

```
$ShowHideMore = $('.post_wrap');
$ShowHideMore.each(function() {
var $times = $(this).children('.pst');
if ($times.length > 5) {
    $ShowHideMore.children(':nth-of-type(n+5)').addClass('moreShown').hide();
    $(this).find('span.message').addClass('more-times').html('+ Show more');
}
});

$(document).on('click', '.post_wrap > span', function() {
var that = $(this);
var thisParent = that.closest('.post_wrap');
if (that.hasClass('more-times')) {
thisParent.find('.moreShown').show();
that.toggleClass('more-times', 'less-times').html('- Show less');
} else {
thisParent.find('.moreShown').hide();
that.toggleClass('more-times', 'less-times').html('- Show more');
}  
});
```

Comment: I'm not very good on jQuery. Can you explain to me a little more

Comment: thanks for your reply. Can you check it for me ? [CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/jEWbWL) and how can i add  Show less button  ?

Comment: This code will not working without this : http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js   . If i remove this from my jquerys then  your code will work.

Comment: You will have to include jquery right before the closing body tag of your document (check here http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_install.asp)